# What causes incrementing a specifc value with ++ in my javascript ES6 class to be such a performance hit?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, emulation, increment

I have a very specific issue I found while writing a Gameboy Emulator in Javascript. I've just finished implementing the audio part and use a simple counter to check when the audio logic needs updating. The reason behind this is because the audio clock is running at a fraction of the emulated CPU clock.

In my emulator, I have 4 different audio channels. All of them are written as a ES6 class with some form of inheritance. Each channel is responsible for tracking a counter so we have a usable clock and perform logic within the audio channel itself. However, when I run the Chrome profiler, I've noticed weird behaviour showing a massive performance hit just incrementing this number:

[image: Big performance hit on incrementing a property]

I've tried different things:

- Making sure I instantiate the property at the start of the class
- Put the value in a temporary variable, incrementing it and putting it back (the last line would cause the same issue)

```
    var a = this.fs;
    a++;
    this.fs = a; //This line would cause the same issue.
```

- Do a bunch of increments and decrements right after eachother to make sure this was not a one-off. Every single change of this variable caused a big performance hit.

```
    //Every line would give a big performance spike causing the emulator to be unplayable.
    this.fs++;
    this.fs--;
    this.fs++;
    this.fs--;
    this.fs++;
    this.fs--;
    this.fs++;
    this.fs--;
    this.fs++;
    this.fs--;
    this.fs++;
    this.fs--;
    this.fs++;
```

So everything I've tried seems to point to the fact that changing the value of the property is causing a massive performance hit. I've read a bit about inline caching the V8 engine does, but haven't found anything useful about this so far.

If anyone wants to see the full source code, you can find the AudioChannel code right here:

http://www.joranderaaff.nl/gameboyso/src/audiochannels.js

If you want to run the emulator and see try to see yourself, you can play it right here:

http://www.joranderaaff.nl/gameboyso/

Especially Pokemon seems to have some trouble during the intro animation of the two pokemon fighting.

One other very weird observation is that wrapping the counter in an object cuts down processing time significantly:

```
//In the constructor:
this.fs = {counter: 0};

//In the step() method:
this.fs.counter++;
```

Edit: I just removed all inheritance based code by duplicating the needed code into each class. This way no call to 'super' is being done anymore. This increases performance a lot. It seems that having classes inherit form each other gives a big performance hit on the V8 engine.

Comment: As you suggested the browser might have a problem with inheritance. Try to use babel, so your code is compiled to es2015. This way your modularity stays intact. And let us know.

Comment: The source file you linked doesn't contain the code you posted here?

Comment: "*All of them are written as a ES6 class*" - no, those "property declarations" in your classes are not part of ES6 `class` syntax. Where exactly do you run this code? Do you transpile it before? You should always initialise *all* of your instance properties in the constructor, or they won't be optimised properly.

Comment: Converting with babel made things even worse, since that code creates a lot of overhead. So far the best option seems to be to have all the code duplicated for the different channels.

As for the ES6 classes not being valid, this was an attempt to let the engine know what properties to expect so there wouldn't be any caching. 

Sorry for not having the exact same property names Bergi. The one we're looking at is this.frameSequencer

Comment: If babel didn't work, why not try to use dependency injection?